# tar files with backslahes on Debian

Tags: linux, shell-script, debian, shell, tar

I need to copy files that contain (Windows-style) backslahes from a Debian 10 pod. I'm having trouble with `GNU tar 1.30` archiving files with backslashes:

```bash
docker run --rm -it debian:10 bash
```

inside the container, for example, run:

```bash
touch C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\\1
touch C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\\2
```

files with backslashes:

```bash
ls -l C\:*

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 14 17:20 'C:\LOG_DOTNET\1'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 14 17:20 'C:\LOG_DOTNET\2'
```

tried to archive with `tar` globbing:

```bash
tar cvf a.tar C\:*

tar: C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\001: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\002: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

tried `find` to print `NUL` character and use `xargs`:

```bash
find . -name C\:\* -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvf a.tar

tar: ./C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\002: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: ./C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\001: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

tried single-quoting each line:

```bash
find . -name C\:\* | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g; s/^/'/; s/$/'/" | xargs tar cvf a.tar

tar: ./C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\002: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: ./C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\001: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I also don't understand why `\00` appears instead of `\\` (seems to be the cause of my problem).

Bonus if your provide `kubectl cp` or `kubectl exec` command to copy such files. :-)

Comment: Exciting.... `tar  cvf a.tar --add-file=C:\\LOG_DOTNET\\1
tar: C\:\\LOG_DOTNET\001: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`
but:
`tar cvf a.tar .
./
./f2
tar: ./a.tar: file is the archive; not dumped
./C:\\LOG_DOTNET\\1
./f1`

Comment: But none of these are special characters, so it’s weird that `tar` can’t deal with them directly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here: [superuser question](https:////superuser.com/questions/148020/using-find-and-tar-with-files-with-special-characters-in-the-name)

```
find . -name C\:\* -print0 | tar --null -T - -cf a.tar
```

From the tar manual:

```
--null Instruct subsequent -T options to read null-terminated names verbatim  (disables  special  handling  of
              names that start with a dash).
```

and for the -T we can use the stdin for source. => Test:

```
find -name 'C:*' -print0 |tar --null -T - -cf a.tar
tar tf a.tar 
./C:\\LOG_DOTNET\\2
./C:\\LOG_DOTNET\\1
```

Comment: `tar -cf a.tar --null -T <(find . -name C\:\* -print0)`